# Xceed word get paragraph font properties

Tags: c#, ms-word, xceed

I need to get the color, font size and font from the below mentioned paragraph(Heading1).
I have looked at [How get paragraph FontName with Docx dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104889/how-get-paragraph-fontname-with-docx-dll) but the font details and color returns null/empty.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

```
                dummyDocument.ApplyTemplate(wordStyleTemplate);
                dummyDocument.InsertParagraph("Heading1").StyleName = "Heading1";

                dummyDocument.Save();
                dummyDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\DEV\StyleTest.docx");

                var templateHeading1 = dummyDocument.Paragraphs.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.StyleName == "Heading1");
                var color = templateHeading1.MagicText[0].formatting.FontColor; //returns null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this Open Xml example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-extract-styles-from-a-word-processing-document) to obtain the entire style sheet for the word document, and then extracted the required styles.